# Zabbix sender. Discovery rules. Host prototypes

Tags: zabbix

I would like to automate host creation on `zabbix` server without using agent on hosts. Tried to use Discovery rules and sending JSON `data` with `zabbix_sender`. But without luck. Server does not accept `data`.

> ```
> Environment:
> Zabbix server 3.4 installed on Centos 7.Hosts with Windows or Ubuntu.
> ```

On server I created `host` with name `zab_trap`
In that host I created Discovery rule with key `zab_trap.discovery` and type `Zabbix_trapper`. Then in Discovery rule I created Host prototype with name {#RH.NAME}.

Command line with JSON "data":

```
zabbix_sender.exe -z zab_server -s zab_trap -k zab_trap.discovery -o "{"data":[{"{#RH.NAME}":"HOST1"}]}"
```

I expected that "HOST1" will be created. But after execution I got:

```
"info from server: "processed: 0; failed: 1; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.000188"
sent: 1; skipped: 0; total: 1"
```

And there is no error in zabbix_server.log (with debug level 5)
I see this:

```
trapper got '{"request":"sender data","data":[{"host":"zab_trap","key":"zab_trap.discovery","value":"'{data:[{{#RH.NAME}:HOST1}]}'"}]}'
```

I think that maybe there is something wrong with JSON syntax.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I have found solution. Problem is hidden in a way to send JSON. As I understood it does not work properly or there is problem with syntax(quotes) if write JSON directly in command line. But it works if zabbix_sender send file with JSON.

Command line:

*zabbix_sender -z zab_server -s zab_trap -i test.json*

File test.json contain line:

*- zab_trap.discovery {"data":[{"{#RH.NAME}":"HOST1"}]}*

Host created.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the command line, without file json, you need to clean the string with:

zabbix_sender.exe -z zab_server -s zab_trap -k zab_trap.discovery -o "$(echo '{"data":[{"{#RH.NAME}":"HOST1"}]}' | tr -cd '[:print:]')"